# How to create shaders for GLES2

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, shader, primitive

I am new to OpenGL ES 2, all my previous work was with OpenGL ES 1.1 but now I have to use OpenGL ES 2.

I have found several tutorials and samples on this but I'm still confused. When I try to change the most common sample that draws a triangle on the screen so that I can draw a polygon I fail and fail huge.

As I understand a polygon depending on the number of vertices could be a line, a triangle, a square or something more complex. I tried to verify that my changes are ok by having 3 vertices so I should get a triangle but obviously I did something wrong as the shader doesn't even compile.

Is there a book on OpenGL ES 2 for dummies? I am very comfortable with OpenGL ES 1.1 but I think I've proven to myself that I'm a dummy when it comes to OpenGL ES 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes long take to understand all Opengl pipelines because of mathematics and the shaders.

Apparently for your case, It can be the best book ([http://www.amazon.com/iPhone-Programming-Developing-Graphical-Applications/dp/0596804822/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1392851323&sr=8-1&keywords=opengl+es+iphone+3d](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596804822))

because the book always compare opengl es 2.0 to es 1.1 and also supports many codes.

And Second choice can be looking the game engines especially oolong engine shows very well how to use opengl es 2.0

https://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/